# MYSQL How do I find the count of events (two time stamps) occurring at the time a creates an account? (for many users)

Tags: mysql

I want to find the number of group_calls that have started and have not ended when a user creates an account.

I'm able to find the count of group_calls occurring at the time of 1 user's account creation, though I'm not able to produce a table that shows the number of group_calls occurring for each user when they created an account.

```
Sample user data:
SELECT created_at from users WHERE created_at between "2021-06-24" AND "2021-06-25"

id  created_at
8193    2021-06-24 00:09:29
8194    2021-06-24 00:22:19
8195    2021-06-24 00:47:28
8196    2021-06-24 01:05:37
8197    2021-06-24 01:06:17
8198    2021-06-24 01:06:45
...

8240    2021-06-24 08:18:04
8241    2021-06-24 08:20:56
8242    2021-06-24 08:29:54
8243    2021-06-24 08:32:49
...
```

This sample query allows me to get the number of group_calls happening when user 8193 created his account:

```
SELECT count(*) from group_calls WHERE "2021-06-24 00:09:29" BETWEEN created_at and ended_at
```

It returns
count(*)
2

When I run this query with a different users creation time:

```
SELECT count(*) from group_calls WHERE "2021-06-24 08:32:49" BETWEEN created_at and ended_at
```

It returns
count(*)
6

I want a table result like this. There should be 1 row for each user for all users in my database.

```
|group_call count | user_id|
|2                | 8193   |
|6                | 8243   |
etc
```

Thank you

Comment: Please include complete sample data and the output you expect from that sample.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated. Hopefully this is more clear. Thank you

Comment: Your example is far from complete. How can the `Event_Count` be different for two accounts created at the same timestamp? Is there any connection between events and users, that has to be considered? If yes, you should include that in your example ... How do you get an event count of 3 or 6? What events are to be included there?

Comment: @derpirscher Okay I've updated the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the two tables and group by the userid. So assuming you have one table

```
users(
  id int,
  created_at datetime,
  ...
)
```

and another table

```
groupcalls(
  created_at datetime,
  ended_at datetime,
  ... 
)
```

You can get your desired result by the following query

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*)
FROM users u INNER JOIN groupcalls gc ON u.created_at BETWEEN gc.created_at AND gc.ended_at
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I only ever knew to join tables by the = operator. I learned something new.